# Oculus Rift / Vulkan : Write to swapchain with a compute shader

Tags: c++, vulkan, oculus

I would like to write to the swapchain generated by OVR with a compute shader.
The problem is that the images don't have the usage `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

The creation of the swapchain is done with `ovr_CreateTextureSwapChainVk` which ask for a flag `BindFlags`. I added the flag `ovrTextureBind_DX_UnorderedAccess` but still the images don't have the correct usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the images don't have the usage `VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT`.

Then you cannot write to a swapchain image directly with a compute shader.

The display engine that provides the swapchain images has the right to decide how you may and may not use them. The only method of interaction which is required is the ability to use them as a color render target; *everything else* is optional.

So you will have to do this another way, perhaps by writing to an intermediate image and copying/rendering it to the swapchain image.